# Splitting dataframe into multiple dataframes based on value from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. df1 is like a dictionary with following value

```
Ticker          INDUSTRY_SECTOR
TLRA_Equity     Communications
KAMN_Equity     Industrial
B_Equity        Industrial
ARNC_Equity     Industrial
RC_Equity       Consumer, Non-cyclical
DAR_Equity      Consumer, Non-cyclical
```

df2 has following values:

```
  Date   TLRA_Equity  KAMN_Equity  B_Equity  ARNC_Equity RC_Equity DAR_Equity
1/1/2000  10              20        30          40        50          60
2/1/2000  15              25        35          45        55          65
3/1/2000  17              27        37          47        57          67
```

I want to split df2 into 3 new dataframe based on `INDUSTRY_SECTOR` in df1  dataframe.

- Date, TLRA_Equity column  should in `Communications` dataframe
- Date, KAMN_Equity,B_Equity, ARNC_Equity column should in `Industrial` dataframe
- Date, RC_Equity, DAR_Equity column should in `Consumer, Non-cyclical` dataframe

Expected output:

- `Communications` dataframe

  ```
  Date   TLRA_Equity  
  1/1/2000  10            
  2/1/2000  15            
  3/1/2000  17
  ```
- `Industrial` dataframe

  ```
  Date    KAMN_Equity  B_Equity  ARNC_Equity 
  1/1/2000  20          30          40       
  2/1/2000  25          35          45       
  3/1/2000  27          37          47
  ```
- `Consumer, Non-cyclical` dataframe

  ```
  Date          RC_Equity DAR_Equity
  1/1/2000        50          60
  2/1/2000        55          65
  3/1/2000        57          67
  ```

Please let me know how to do in a efficient way.  What i was trying to do concatenate the column names for example `Communications_TLRA_Equity` and then split dataframe based on first half of column name.

Code:

```
col_names = df2.columns.values.tolist()
d_cols = df2.columns.map(df1.set_index('Ticker')['INDUSTRY_SECTOR'].get)
print(d_cols)
df.columns = [d_cols + "_"  str(col) for col in df.columns]

for sector, df_sector in df.columns.str.split('_').str[0].tolist():
     print(sector)
     print(df_sector)
```

But this is complex. Need better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of dataframes using groupby,

```
dfs = [df2.set_index('Date')[ticker].reset_index() for ticker in df1.groupby('INDUSTRY_SECTOR').Ticker.apply(list)]


dfs[0]

    Date    TLRA_Equity
0   1/1/2000    10
1   2/1/2000    15
2   3/1/2000    17


dfs[1]

    Date    RC_Equity   DAR_Equity
0   1/1/2000    50      60
1   2/1/2000    55      65
2   3/1/2000    57      67

dfs[2]


    Date    KAMN_Equity B_Equity    ARNC_Equity
0   1/1/2000    20      30          40
1   2/1/2000    25      35          45
2   3/1/2000    27      37          47
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a `dict` of frames, with the key being your 'INDUSTRY_SECTOR` name.

First create a dict of INDUSTRY_SECTOR: Ticker columns

```
g = df1.groupby('INDUSTRY_SECTOR')['Ticker'].apply(list).to_dict()
print(g)

{'Communications': ['TLRA_Equity'], 'Consumer, Non-cyclical': ['RC_Equity', 'DAR_Equity'], 'Industrial': ['KAMN_Equity', 'B_Equity', 'ARNC_Equity']}
```

Then create a dict comprehension:

```
frames = {k:df2.set_index('Date')[v] for k,v in g.items()}

print(frames)

{'Communications':           TLRA_Equity
Date                 
1/1/2000           10
2/1/2000           15
3/1/2000           17,
 'Consumer, Non-cyclical':           RC_Equity  DAR_Equity
Date                           
1/1/2000         50          60
2/1/2000         55          65
3/1/2000         57          67,
 'Industrial':           KAMN_Equity  B_Equity  ARNC_Equity
Date                                        
1/1/2000           20        30           40
2/1/2000           25        35           45
3/1/2000           27        37           47}
```

N.B.

As @Parfait  pointed out, to include the `Date` column, you'll need to set it as the index in the dict comprehension. If you don't want `Date` as index, instead use:

```
frames = {k:df2.set_index('Date')[v].reset_index() for k,v in g.items()}
```

Comment: Great! Working fine :)

Comment: @ArvinthKumar ... I would have thought this be the accepted answer as you get data frames with named objects: `frames['Communications']`, `frames['Industrial']`, etc.

Comment: @Parfait .. Both the answers are good. While accepting I didn't realize the difference in output.